# PHP redirect to another page through a blank page

Tags: php, redirect

It sounds easy but I've got myself tangled already. How do I redirect to another page and in between i wish to show an empty page with some texts for a specific time. I looked for sleep(); and other options but none of them offer what i want.

```
<?php 
require ('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $gender = $_POST['gender'];
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $add1 = $_POST['add1'];
   $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
   $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
   $mail = $_POST['mail'];
   $uname = $_POST['uname'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
   $cell = $_POST['cell'];

   $complete_add = $add1 . " ".  $add2;
   $query = "INSERT INTO login(username, password) VALUES('$uname', '$pass')";
   $run = mysql_query($query);
if(!$run)
{
    echo "Failed: Username already registered <br>";
    die();

}
   $query2 = "INSERT INTO signup(First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Birth_Date, Address, NIC, Email, Username, Password, Contact)
 VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$date', '$complete_add', '$cnic', '$mail', '$uname', '$pass', '$cell')";
   $run2 = mysql_query($query2);
echo "Congratulations! You have registered now. <br> You will now be redirected to Item lists...";
// sleep(5);
exit(header('Location: view.php'));
//  header( "refresh:2;url=http://localhost/view.php" );

}

?>
```

Comment: `header( "refresh:5;url=a_page.php" );`

You will need move your `echo` onto that page though, if you `echo` before a `header` then it won't work

Comment: @JoeP I want the message on an empty page not on the same or the destination page! is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I'd say just put a normal header redirect after your query to your otherwise empty page.  Then, on your 'empty' page, declare `header( "refresh:5;url=a_page.php" );` first and then `echo` your confirmation after it.  It should display the message for 5 seconds and then redirect afterwards.

Comment: plus 1 for that! Something that I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to our discussion on the comments, my suggestion is as follows:

**Page1.php:**

```
<?php
// your sql query as before
if($run2)
    header("Location: Page2.php"); // normal redirect after completing your sql query
?>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<?php
header("refresh:5;url=Page3.php" );
echo "Confirmation message displayed for 5 seconds before redirect";
?>
```

**Page3.php**

```
<?php
// This would be your Item List, or whatever you were redirecting to
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the guy to this page after successful entry or registration.

**main_refresh_landing.php**

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=someurl.php");
echo "Congrats, there's some text waiting for you---->";
//user will be redirected after 4 seconds.
```

Or better

```
    <?php 
    require ('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['check']))
    {
       $fname = $_POST['fname'];
       $lname = $_POST['lname'];
       $gender = $_POST['gender'];
       $date = $_POST['date'];
       $add1 = $_POST['add1'];
       $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
       $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
       $mail = $_POST['mail'];
       $uname = $_POST['uname'];
       $pass = $_POST['pass'];
       $cell = $_POST['cell'];

       $complete_add = $add1 . " ".  $add2;
       $query = "INSERT INTO login(username, password) VALUES('$uname', '$pass')";
       $run = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$run)
    {
        echo "Failed: Username already registered <br>";
        die();

    }
       $query2 = "INSERT INTO signup(First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Birth_Date, Address, NIC, Email, Username, Password, Contact)
     VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$date', '$complete_add', '$cnic', '$mail', '$uname', '$pass', '$cell')";
       $run2 = mysql_query($query2);
    if($run2)
    {
header("Refresh: 2; url=main_refresh_landing.php");
    echo "Congratulations! You have registered now. <br> You will now be redirected to Item lists...";
    }

    }
```

Comment: as much as it looks fascinating, i wish it worked too! Nothing happens, i don't get the echo message, "The one  I want on an empty page". I used your second "better" method.

Comment: @MuneerKhan I've updated my answer, sorry had some typo.

Comment: JoeP's technique was exactly what I was looking for. Anyways Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Redirection ways

**PHP**

```
<?php
    header( "refresh:5;url=view.php" );
    echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="view.php">here</a>.';
?>
```

**Meta tag**:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://localhost/view.php">';
```

**JavaScript**:

If it has to be in the script use setTimeout like:

```
echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.open('http://localhost/view.php');
}, 5000);</script>";
```

Comment: What about the message I want to display? and that too on an empty page, not on the same or the destination page!

Comment: @MuneerKhan you can save message in session then can access it from next page.

Comment: I'm still learning PHP, for now I've got it sorted out but i definitely will look for a way to do it with sessions too! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript for this.

Php code should execute then be displayed in the browser

so sleeping while executing a script...

in javascript you can do this

```
<script>setTimeout(function() {window.location="http://www.google.com";}, 3000);</script>
```

The page loads with whatever you want to display, waits 3000ms (i.e 3 seconds) and redirect to google.com.

Cheers

Comment: Why should Javascript be used?  The question asks for a PHP resolution

Comment: Do you have a way to do on the empty page? I mean the display message should be on a separate empty page (one like that appears when you call a die(); function)

Comment: @MuneerKhan: I dont understand.